# jQuery.post() callback fails to execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using `jQuery.post()` and everything is working just fine, except that the callback function isn't being called.

Data is getting sent properly and the server is receiving it properly etc, but nothing happens afterwards. I have tried copying reference code to no avail.

This is the inline Javascript I'm using:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submit_login_cb(data,status) {
            alert(data);
        }
        function submit_login() {
            $.post("http://localhost:8051/", $("#login_form").serialize(), function(data,status){submit_login_cb(data,status);}, "json");
        }
        </script>
    </head>
```

Why is the callback not working?

**Edit: the `statusText` field of the returned `jqXHR` object just says "error"...Nothing else happens though (the POST request registers on the server).**

**Edit: Chrome Developer Tools is printing this to the console:**
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8051/. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: do you get any javascript error?

Comment: @kleinohad No, it just fails silently.

Comment: Is the server responding properly? Have you tried adding an error handler to the returned [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)?

Comment: @muistooshort The server is responding properly. Sorry, I don't know how to error handle jQuery.post()...I thought you were supposed to use callbacks to handle failures

Comment: does your code work if you simplefy the callback function? I mean replace 'function(data,status){submit_login_cb(data,status);' by an ordinary 'alert("test")'.

Comment: @reporter I have tried that earlier and unfortunately it did not work. It's as if the callback argument is just ignored altogether.

Comment: have you debugged using Firebug or another tool?

Comment: @mfadel No...I'm kind of new to this so I was using Notepad++ because I haven't searched for a better tool...going to get Firebug now I suppose.

Comment: @mfadel Ah. There's actually an error. My bad...

Comment: @mfadel It's still a client-side error (I know for a fact that the server is receiving and returning data), and I have no idea what it is. All I know is that the `statusText` of the return `jqXHR` says "error"...anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Would you mind to post source code from php file. That would be more helpful for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry forgot to update this, to fix this, just allow a Null Origin on your WSGI server.